# How to Check Cryptocurrency Transaction Status

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have `TransactionId` of a transaction, i want to  check status of this when user send transaction id.

How do I know a transaction has been successfully received?

Answer (score 0):

For query a transaction in a blockchain you must know the transaction network first

Assuming the transaction is done in ethereum network

For example if the transaction done in ethereum network you can see the transaction detail in [etherscan](https://etherscan.io)

there is 2 approach if you want to do it in your application

1 : You can use a third party block explorer API like [Infura](https://www.infura.io)

2 : You can install and connect to an ethereum node and get all transactions

Use [This DOC](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/run-a-node/) if you choose this approach

Other blockchain networks is follow this instructions as well and you can search for a block explorer API or run a node and get transactions directly from the node

Comment: i have multy transaction network.

Comment: then you should implement one of mentioned approach for each network or use third party block explorer API that can connect to multiple networks